# Adding name space to ejabberd server

Tags: xmpp, ejabberd, spectrum, strophe

I am using ejabberd-2.1.2 server. How can I add new name space to existing ejabberd server. 
I would like to add name space ('http://jabber.org/protocol/rosterx') XEP-0144 Roster Item exchange.

Thanks,
sathi.

Comment: What are you trying to do? Would a custom X stanza do the trick? Are you trying to add custom stanza processing on the server side?

Answer (score 0):

Create a module, name it something like `mod_rosterx.erl`.  Add it into your `ejabberd.cfg` file.

The contents of this file should be something like the following.  You'll need to actually write your code in the `process_local_iq` functions.  Also, this will handle IS stanzas addressed to the server, not addressed to other clients.  Adjust as needed!

```
-module(mod_rosterx).
-behavior(gen_mod).

-export([start/2, stop/1, process_local_iq/3]).

-include("ejabberd/src/ejabberd.hrl").
-include("ejabberd/src/jlib.hrl").

-define(NS_ROSTERX, "http://jabber.org/protocol/rosterx").

start(Host, Opts) ->
    IQDisc = gen_mod:get_opt(iqdisc, Opts, one_queue),
    mod_disco:register_feature(Host, ?NS_ROSTERX),
    gen_iq_handler:add_iq_handler(ejabberd_local, Host, ?NS_ROSTERX, ?MODULE, process_local_iq, IQDisc).

stop(Host) ->
    gen_iq_handler:remove_iq_handler(ejabberd_local, Host, ?NS_ROSTERX).


process_local_iq(From, To, {iq, ID, set, NS, Language, SubElement}) ->
    {iq, ID, error, NS, Language, []};
process_local_iq(_, _, {iq, ID, get, NS, Language, SubElement}) ->
    {iq, ID, error, NS, Language, []}.
```

Comment: could you please elaborate on "Also, this will handle IS stanzas addressed to the server, not addressed to other clients. Adjust as needed!"...it will help a lot...Thanks